# Validación de Imagen en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, formularios, imagen, validación

Tengo una breve consulta sobre un formulario en LARAVEL 5:

Tengo un campo de **imagen** y otro de **video** funcionan correctamente, pero, cuando tengo un error (por validación) por ejemplo por campo requerido en el nombre, la imagen o video se pierden y tengo que volver a cargar la imagen o video. Pero el nombre si lo cargo bien, no lo pierdo al darle **Guardar**.

Formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al cargar una imagen sin NOMBRE, y nombre es requerido voy a tener un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error: como se ve en la imagen al validar el nombre pierdo la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo que volver a cargar, y para los usuarios es molesto hacer eso.

He ocupado una función que trae laravel **old()**, pero no pude solución el problema.

Además uso un archivo request para las validaciones:

```
return [
        'name'   =>  'required|max:255',
        'picture'   =>  'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png',
    ];
```

Y en el controlador desde store lo llamó.

Estoy usando **LaravelCollective**:

```
{{ Form::file('picture', ['id' => 'file_url']) }}
```

Alguna idea como debería resolver, si tendría que usar Javascript o existe alguna forma de hacerlo desde el framework.

Comment: puedes utilizar `old`, en tu etiqueta html de esta forma: <input type="file" value="{{old('picture')}}" name="picture">, y lo mismo para el nombre

Comment: tendrás que usar ajax (o convertir la imagen a blob y guardarla en un hidden), por cuestiones de seguridad los INPUT de tipo FILE no se pueden "precargar" con old() (imaginate que esté oculto y pida subir un archivo específico sin que el usuario se entere)

Comment: ** otra opción es validar con javascript antes del form submit, así no pierde las referencias a los archivos

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar de validar a traves de javascript.